# KeyError: 'Load Balancer Addresses'

Tags: python, boto3, aws-elb

I have been working with BOTO 3 to describe all load balancers available in the account. I used the following snippet of code:

```py
'elbv2=boto3.client('elbv2',aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name=region)
response=elbv2.describe_load_balancers()

print(response)
```

The response here stores the `dict` with all the information, like so:

```
{
    'LoadBalancers': [{
        'LoadBalancerArn': 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:407203256002:loadbalancer/net/aws-lb-02/9d4b15bfd6f579d3',
        'DNSName': 'aws-lb-02-9d4b15bfd6f579d3.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
        'CanonicalHostedZoneId': 'ZVDDRBQ08TROA',
        'CreatedTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 31, 11, 45, 6, 729000, tzinfo = tzutc()),
        'LoadBalancerName': 'aws-lb-02',
        'Scheme': 'internet-facing',
        'VpcId': 'vpc-0be01860',
        'State': {
            'Code': 'active'
        },
        'Type': 'network',
        'AvailabilityZones': [{
            'ZoneName': 'ap-south-1a',
            'SubnetId': 'subnet-ed5fb986',
            'LoadBalancerAddresses': []
        }, {
            'ZoneName': 'ap-south-1b',
            'SubnetId': 'subnet-89d285c5',
            'LoadBalancerAddresses': []
        }]]}"'
```

I want to access `LoadBalancerAddress` , which I tried like this:

```py
LoadBalancers=response['LoadBalancers']
for i in LoadBalancers:
  AvailabilityZones=i['AvailabilityZones']
  for j in AvailabilityZones:
    LoadBalancerAddresses=i['LoadBalancerAddresses']
```

However, it throws an error saying that there is a keyword error for `LoadBalancerAddresses`, which I fail to understand.
Please help in how should I access the variable.

Comment: A `KeyError` occurs when the program cannot find the key in the dict object. Please check if `LoadBalancerAddresses` are in all of your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use nested list comprehension here, like that:

```
addresses = [x['LoadBalancerAddresses'] for res in aaa['LoadBalancers'] for x in res['AvailabilityZones']]
```

or with ordinar nested lists:

```
addresses = []
for bal in aaa['LoadBalancers']:
    for zones in bal['AvailabilityZones']:
        addresses += zones['LoadBalancerAddresses']
```

Answer (score 2):

You mistyped `j['LoadBalancerAddresses']` as `i['LoadBalancerAddresses']`. Since there are no keys named `LoadBalancerAddresses` directly under `response['LoadBalancers']`, your program throws a `KeyError`.

The fixed version:

```py
LoadBalancers=response['LoadBalancers']
for i in LoadBalancers:
  AvailabilityZones=i['AvailabilityZones']
  for j in AvailabilityZones:
    LoadBalancerAddresses=j['LoadBalancerAddresses']
```

As a safety option, it's good practice to check if the key exists before you access it, such as:

```py
for j in AvailabilityZones:
    if "LoadBalancerAddresses" in j:
        LoadBalancerAddresses=j['LoadBalancerAddresses']
    else:
        print("The key does not exist")
```